what is the key binding to open function documentation?
Could someone please help me with this: what is the keybinding to open those pop-up windows in Zed editor which show the function description? See my screenshot. In other editors it’s sometimes called “code lense”.
I’ve looked everywhere and I simply cannot find it (if I only knew how the action is called in the settings file…). I’m using a tiling window manager, so I don’t want to use the mouse every time. Thanks.


Someone already gave me the answer elsewhere.
It is the "editor::Hover" action, this is the default keymap excerpt:
"context": "Editor",
    "bindings": {
      "ctrl-k ctrl-i": "editor::Hover",
...

I just had to remap it because I already use ctrl-k for something else.
